# Errors when install QEMU from source code

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, qemu, configure, ninja

When I want to install QEMU from source code, I followed this article's recommended method of installation [Emulating CXL Shared Memory Devices in QEMU](https://memverge.com/cxl-qemuemulating-cxl-shared-memory-devices-in-qemu/).when I started to make ,errors happened.

```bash
[1117/2990] Compiling C object libqemuutil.a.p/util_userfaultfd.c.o
FAILED: libqemuutil.a.p/util_userfaultfd.c.o 
cc -m64 -mcx16 -Ilibqemuutil.a.p -I. -I.. -Isubprojects/libvhost-user -I../subprojects/libvhost-user -Iqapi -Itrace -Iui -Iui/shader -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=gnu11 -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wendif-labels -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-missing-include-dirs -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-psabi /mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu/linux-headers linux-headers -iquote . -iquote /mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu -iquote /mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu/include -iquote /mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu/host/include/x86_64 -iquote /mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu/host/include/generic -iquote /mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu/tcg/i386 -pthread -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fwrapv -fPIE -MD -MQ libqemuutil.a.p/util_userfaultfd.c.o -MF libqemuutil.a.p/util_userfaultfd.c.o.d -o libqemuutil.a.p/util_userfaultfd.c.o -c ../util/userfaultfd.c
../util/userfaultfd.c: In function ‘uffd_open’:
../util/userfaultfd.c:54:32: error: ‘USERFAULTFD_IOC_NEW’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘USERFAULTFD_H’?
   54 |         return ioctl(uffd_dev, USERFAULTFD_IOC_NEW, flags);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                USERFAULTFD_H
../util/userfaultfd.c:54:32: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

the error is that USERFAULTFD_IOC_NEW can't be find,there is no USERFAULTFD_IOC_NEW in `/usr/include/linux/userfaultfd.h` , however ,there is a linux-headers folder ，USERFAULTFD_IOC_NEW is definded in `qemu/linux-headers/linux/userfaultfd.h`.
Combined with the `/mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu/linux-headers linux-headers` in the compile command, it may be that the headers in this folder are intended to replace the headers in `/usr/include/linux`, but I don't know why it didn't work.
my cpu is AMD EPYC 7773X 64-Core Processor ,linux is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LT
This warning also appears when compiling other files：

```bash
[1331/2990] Compiling C object libblock.fa.p/block_blklogwrites.c.o
cc: warning: /mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu/linux-headers: linker input file unused because linking not done
cc: warning: linux-headers: linker input file unused because linking not done
[1332/2990] Compiling C object tests/qtest/libqos/libqos.fa.p/pci.c.o
cc: warning: /mnt/nvme0/home/shs/qemu/linux-headers: linker input file unused because linking not done
cc: warning: linux-headers: linker input file unused because linking not done
[1333/2990] Compiling C object libblock.fa.p/block_backup.c.o
```

configure commond:

```bash
../configure --prefix=/opt/qemu-jic23 --target-list=i386-softmmu,x86_64-softmmu --enable-libpmem --enable-slirp
```

the makefile is as below:

```
# Makefile for QEMU.

ifneq ($(words $(subst :, ,$(CURDIR))), 1)
  $(error main directory cannot contain spaces nor colons)
endif

# Always point to the root of the build tree (needs GNU make).
BUILD_DIR=$(CURDIR)

# Before including a proper config-host.mak, assume we are in the source tree
SRC_PATH=.

# Don't use implicit rules or variables
# we have explicit rules for everything
MAKEFLAGS += -rR

SHELL = bash -o pipefail

# Usage: $(call quiet-command,command and args,"NAME","args to print")
# This will run "command and args", and either:
#  if V=1 just print the whole command and args
#  otherwise print the 'quiet' output in the format "  NAME     args to print"
# NAME should be a short name of the command, 7 letters or fewer.
# If called with only a single argument, will print nothing in quiet mode.
quiet-command-run = $(if $(V),,$(if $2,printf "  %-7s %s\n" $2 $3 && ))$1
quiet-@ = $(if $(V),,@)
quiet-command = $(quiet-@)$(call quiet-command-run,$1,$2,$3)

UNCHECKED_GOALS := TAGS gtags cscope ctags dist \
    help check-help print-% \
    docker docker-% vm-help vm-test vm-build-%

all:
.PHONY: all clean distclean recurse-all dist msi FORCE

# Don't try to regenerate Makefile or configure
# We don't generate any of them
Makefile: ;
configure: ;

# All following code might depend on configuration variables
ifneq ($(wildcard config-host.mak),)
include config-host.mak

include Makefile.prereqs
Makefile.prereqs: config-host.mak

git-submodule-update:
.git-submodule-status: git-submodule-update config-host.mak
Makefile: .git-submodule-status

.PHONY: git-submodule-update
git-submodule-update:
ifneq ($(GIT_SUBMODULES_ACTION),ignore)
    $(call quiet-command, \
        (GIT="$(GIT)" "$(SRC_PATH)/scripts/git-submodule.sh" $(GIT_SUBMODULES_ACTION) $(GIT_SUBMODULES)), \
        "GIT","$(GIT_SUBMODULES)")
endif

# 0. ensure the build tree is okay

# Check that we're not trying to do an out-of-tree build from
# a tree that's been used for an in-tree build.
ifneq ($(realpath $(SRC_PATH)),$(realpath .))
ifneq ($(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)/config-host.mak),)
$(error This is an out of tree build but your source tree ($(SRC_PATH)) \
seems to have been used for an in-tree build. You can fix this by running \
"$(MAKE) distclean && rm -rf *-linux-user *-softmmu" in your source tree)
endif
endif

# force a rerun of configure if config-host.mak is too old or corrupted
ifeq ($(MESON),)
.PHONY: config-host.mak
x := $(shell rm -rf meson-private meson-info meson-logs)
endif
ifeq ($(NINJA),)
.PHONY: config-host.mak
x := $(shell rm -rf meson-private meson-info meson-logs)
else
export NINJA
endif
ifeq ($(wildcard build.ninja),)
.PHONY: config-host.mak
x := $(shell rm -rf meson-private meson-info meson-logs)
endif
ifeq ($(origin prefix),file)
.PHONY: config-host.mak
x := $(shell rm -rf meson-private meson-info meson-logs)
endif

# 1. ensure config-host.mak is up-to-date
config-host.mak: $(SRC_PATH)/configure $(SRC_PATH)/scripts/meson-buildoptions.sh $(SRC_PATH)/VERSION
    @echo config-host.mak is out-of-date, running configure
    @if test -f meson-private/coredata.dat; then \
      ./config.status --skip-meson; \
    else \
      ./config.status && touch build.ninja.stamp; \
    fi

# 2. meson.stamp exists if meson has run at least once (so ninja reconfigure
# works), but otherwise never needs to be updated
meson-private/coredata.dat: meson.stamp
meson.stamp: config-host.mak
    @touch meson.stamp

# 3. ensure generated build files are up-to-date

ifneq ($(NINJA),)
Makefile.ninja: build.ninja
    $(quiet-@){ \
      echo 'ninja-targets = \'; \
      $(NINJA) -t targets all | sed 's/:.*//; $$!s/$$/ \\/'; \
      echo 'build-files = \'; \
      $(NINJA) -t query build.ninja | sed -n '1,/^  input:/d; /^  outputs:/q; s/$$/ \\/p'; \
    } > $@.tmp && mv $@.tmp $@
-include Makefile.ninja
endif

ifneq ($(MESON),)
# A separate rule is needed for Makefile dependencies to avoid -n
build.ninja: build.ninja.stamp
$(build-files):
build.ninja.stamp: meson.stamp $(build-files)
    $(MESON) setup --reconfigure $(SRC_PATH) && touch $@

Makefile.mtest: build.ninja scripts/mtest2make.py
    $(MESON) introspect --targets --tests --benchmarks | $(PYTHON) scripts/mtest2make.py > $@
-include Makefile.mtest

.PHONY: update-buildoptions
all update-buildoptions: $(SRC_PATH)/scripts/meson-buildoptions.sh
$(SRC_PATH)/scripts/meson-buildoptions.sh: $(SRC_PATH)/meson_options.txt
    $(MESON) introspect --buildoptions $(SRC_PATH)/meson.build | $(PYTHON) \
      scripts/meson-buildoptions.py > $@.tmp && mv $@.tmp $@
endif

# 4. Rules to bridge to other makefiles

ifneq ($(NINJA),)
# Filter out long options to avoid flags like --no-print-directory which
# may result in false positive match for MAKE.n
MAKE.n = $(findstring n,$(firstword $(filter-out --%,$(MAKEFLAGS))))
MAKE.k = $(findstring k,$(firstword $(filter-out --%,$(MAKEFLAGS))))
MAKE.q = $(findstring q,$(firstword $(filter-out --%,$(MAKEFLAGS))))
MAKE.nq = $(if $(word 2, $(MAKE.n) $(MAKE.q)),nq)
NINJAFLAGS = $(if $V,-v) $(if $(MAKE.n), -n) $(if $(MAKE.k), -k0) \
        $(filter-out -j, $(lastword -j1 $(filter -l% -j%, $(MAKEFLAGS)))) \
        -d keepdepfile
ninja-cmd-goals = $(or $(MAKECMDGOALS), all)
ninja-cmd-goals += $(foreach g, $(MAKECMDGOALS), $(.ninja-goals.$g))

makefile-targets := build.ninja ctags TAGS cscope dist clean
# "ninja -t targets" also lists all prerequisites.  If build system
# files are marked as PHONY, however, Make will always try to execute
# "ninja build.ninja".
ninja-targets := $(filter-out $(build-files) $(makefile-targets), $(ninja-targets))
.PHONY: $(ninja-targets) run-ninja
$(ninja-targets): run-ninja

# Use "| cat" to give Ninja a more "make-y" output.  Use "+" to bypass the
# --output-sync line.
run-ninja: config-host.mak
ifneq ($(filter $(ninja-targets), $(ninja-cmd-goals)),)
    +$(if $(MAKE.nq),@:,$(quiet-@)$(NINJA) $(NINJAFLAGS) \
       $(sort $(filter $(ninja-targets), $(ninja-cmd-goals))) | cat)
endif
endif

ifeq ($(CONFIG_PLUGIN),y)
.PHONY: plugins
plugins:
    $(call quiet-command,\
        $(MAKE) $(SUBDIR_MAKEFLAGS) -C contrib/plugins V="$(V)", \
        "BUILD", "example plugins")
endif # $(CONFIG_PLUGIN)

else # config-host.mak does not exist
ifneq ($(filter-out $(UNCHECKED_GOALS),$(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(if $(MAKECMDGOALS),,fail))
$(error Please call configure before running make)
endif
endif # config-host.mak does not exist

SUBDIR_MAKEFLAGS=$(if $(V),,--no-print-directory --quiet)

include $(SRC_PATH)/tests/Makefile.include

all: recurse-all

ROMS_RULES=$(foreach t, all clean distclean, $(addsuffix /$(t), $(ROMS)))
.PHONY: $(ROMS_RULES)
$(ROMS_RULES):
    $(call quiet-command,$(MAKE) $(SUBDIR_MAKEFLAGS) -C $(dir $@) V="$(V)" TARGET_DIR="$(dir $@)" $(notdir $@),)

.PHONY: recurse-all recurse-clean
recurse-all: $(addsuffix /all, $(ROMS))
recurse-clean: $(addsuffix /clean, $(ROMS))
recurse-distclean: $(addsuffix /distclean, $(ROMS))

######################################################################

clean: recurse-clean
    -$(quiet-@)test -f build.ninja && $(NINJA) $(NINJAFLAGS) -t clean || :
    -$(quiet-@)test -f build.ninja && $(NINJA) $(NINJAFLAGS) clean-ctlist || :
    find . \( -name '*.so' -o -name '*.dll' -o \
          -name '*.[oda]' -o -name '*.gcno' \) -type f \
        ! -path ./roms/edk2/ArmPkg/Library/GccLto/liblto-aarch64.a \
        ! -path ./roms/edk2/ArmPkg/Library/GccLto/liblto-arm.a \
        -exec rm {} +
    rm -f TAGS cscope.* *~ */*~

VERSION = $(shell cat $(SRC_PATH)/VERSION)

dist: qemu-$(VERSION).tar.bz2

qemu-%.tar.bz2:
    $(SRC_PATH)/scripts/make-release "$(SRC_PATH)" "$(patsubst qemu-%.tar.bz2,%,$@)"

distclean: clean recurse-distclean
    -$(quiet-@)test -f build.ninja && $(NINJA) $(NINJAFLAGS) -t clean -g || :
    rm -f config-host.mak Makefile.prereqs
    rm -f tests/tcg/*/config-target.mak tests/tcg/config-host.mak
    rm -f config.status
    rm -f roms/seabios/config.mak
    rm -f qemu-plugins-ld.symbols qemu-plugins-ld64.symbols
    rm -f *-config-target.h *-config-devices.mak *-config-devices.h
    rm -rf meson-private meson-logs meson-info compile_commands.json
    rm -f Makefile.ninja Makefile.mtest build.ninja.stamp meson.stamp
    rm -f config.log
    rm -f linux-headers/asm
    rm -Rf .sdk qemu-bundle

find-src-path = find "$(SRC_PATH)" -path "$(SRC_PATH)/meson" -prune -o \
    -type l -prune -o \( -name "*.[chsS]" -o -name "*.[ch].inc" \)

.PHONY: ctags
ctags:
    $(call quiet-command,           \
        rm -f "$(SRC_PATH)/"tags,   \
        "CTAGS", "Remove old tags")
    $(call quiet-command, \
        $(find-src-path) -exec ctags        \
        -f "$(SRC_PATH)/"tags --append {} +,    \
        "CTAGS", "Re-index $(SRC_PATH)")

.PHONY: gtags
gtags:
    $(call quiet-command,           \
        rm -f "$(SRC_PATH)/"GTAGS;  \
        rm -f "$(SRC_PATH)/"GRTAGS;     \
        rm -f "$(SRC_PATH)/"GPATH,  \
        "GTAGS", "Remove old $@ files")
    $(call quiet-command,               \
            (cd $(SRC_PATH) &&          \
         $(find-src-path) -print | gtags -f -), \
        "GTAGS", "Re-index $(SRC_PATH)")

.PHONY: TAGS
TAGS:
    $(call quiet-command,           \
        rm -f "$(SRC_PATH)/"TAGS,   \
        "TAGS", "Remove old $@")
    $(call quiet-command,               \
        $(find-src-path) -exec etags        \
        -f "$(SRC_PATH)/"TAGS --append {} +,    \
        "TAGS", "Re-index $(SRC_PATH)")

.PHONY: cscope
cscope:
    $(call quiet-command,           \
        rm -f "$(SRC_PATH)/"cscope.* ,  \
        "cscope", "Remove old $@ files")
    $(call quiet-command,                   \
        ($(find-src-path) -print | sed -e 's,^\./,,'    \
        > "$(SRC_PATH)/cscope.files"),          \
        "cscope", "Create file list")
    $(call quiet-command,               \
        cscope -b -i"$(SRC_PATH)/cscope.files"  \
        -f"$(SRC_PATH)"/cscope.out,         \
        "cscope", "Re-index $(SRC_PATH)")

# Needed by "meson install"
export DESTDIR

include $(SRC_PATH)/tests/lcitool/Makefile.include
include $(SRC_PATH)/tests/docker/Makefile.include
include $(SRC_PATH)/tests/vm/Makefile.include

print-help-run = printf "  %-30s - %s\\n" "$1" "$2"
print-help = @$(call print-help-run,$1,$2)

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo  'Generic targets:'
    $(call print-help,all,Build all)
    $(call print-help,dir/file.o,Build specified target only)
    $(call print-help,install,Install QEMU, documentation and tools)
    $(call print-help,ctags/gtags/TAGS,Generate tags file for editors)
    $(call print-help,cscope,Generate cscope index)
    $(call print-help,sparse,Run sparse on the QEMU source)
    @echo  ''
ifeq ($(CONFIG_PLUGIN),y)
    @echo  'Plugin targets:'
    $(call print-help,plugins,Build the example TCG plugins)
    @echo  ''
endif
    @echo  'Cleaning targets:'
    $(call print-help,clean,Remove most generated files but keep the config)
    $(call print-help,distclean,Remove all generated files)
    $(call print-help,dist,Build a distributable tarball)
    @echo  ''
    @echo  'Test targets:'
    $(call print-help,check,Run all tests (check-help for details))
    $(call print-help,bench,Run all benchmarks)
    $(call print-help,lcitool-help,Help about targets for managing build environment manifests)
    $(call print-help,docker-help,Help about targets running tests inside containers)
    $(call print-help,vm-help,Help about targets running tests inside VM)
    @echo  ''
    @echo  'Documentation targets:'
    $(call print-help,html man,Build documentation in specified format)
    @echo  ''
ifdef CONFIG_WIN32
    @echo  'Windows targets:'
    $(call print-help,installer,Build NSIS-based installer for QEMU)
    $(call print-help,msi,Build MSI-based installer for qemu-ga)
    @echo  ''
endif
    $(call print-help,$(MAKE) [targets],(quiet build, default))
    $(call print-help,$(MAKE) V=1 [targets],(verbose build))

# will delete the target of a rule if commands exit with a nonzero exit status
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

print-%:
    @echo '$*=$($*)'
```

I don't know the reason of this problem.Does anyone know why this error occurs and how to fix it?If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you specifically want to use that experimental work-in-progress CXL emulation? If so, try contacting the blog authors. If you don't care about CXL, you should build an upstream QEMU release, not from that branch.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why that error message is happening, but if you don't have a /usr/include/linux/userfaultfd.h at all, make sure you have the linux-libc-dev package installed.

Comment: I encountered the same error when building the release version，and I am sure `/usr/include/linux/userfaultfd.h` exist.@Peter Maydell

Comment: Hmm. Well, I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, my /usr/include/linux/userfaultfd.h also does not have USERFAULTFD_IOC_NEW in it, and upstream QEMU builds fine on my system... I'm not interested in debugging whatever's going on with that fork, but how exactly are you building upstream QEMU ?

Comment: maybe the configure command is different ,I use `../configure --prefix=/opt/qemu-jic23 --target-list=i386-softmmu,x86_64-softmmu --enable-libpmem --enable-slirp`，how do you configure it ?@Peter Maydell

Comment: I cloned this repository from gitlab，did you clone it from github Official QEMU mirror?I clone it from https://gitlab.com/jic23/qemu

Comment: Use the official gitlab QEMU repo, the one the QEMU web page points you at: https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu

Comment: Even I use the officail gitlab QEMU,I met the same problem,so sad，Have you installed any dependencies in advance?@Peter Maydell

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the released `stable-8.1` version of QEMU? I try to build QEMU of this version and meet the same errors. But when I build QEMU of 8.0 version, all errors are not occurring and QEMU is successfully installed. (My Linux version is 5.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that the object files should be clean before starting a new compilation.

```
cd ./qemu
git clean -xdf
make -j8
```

Hope it also helps you.